# How to debug CSS codes?

Tags: css, debugging

How does one generally debug CSS and resolve issues when some elements on the page are not appearing as they should? For now, I have to painfully comment out CSS declarations one by one to understand how the styles are getting displayed.

Comment: Chrome Dev Tools is your friend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you can not "debug" CSS, because it is not a scripting language, you can utilize the Chrome DevTools Elements panel to inspect an element & view the Styles pane on the right.

This will give you insights as to the styles being overridden or ignored (line threw).

`CTRL + SHIFT + I`

To Find Errors & Warnings use `CSSLint`

Answer (score 2):

Debugging CSS and HTML code bugs can really ruin your application design. There are multiple ways to debug CSS and HTML code. There are few things or ways you should consider the debugging and taking care while developing HTML or writing CSS.

> Check your syntax errors with http://csslint.net/. It provides the
> nice tool and highlights a line where an error occurs.
>
> **Closely review your cross-browser compatibility issues.** A site looks nice and beautiful in a firefox but sometimes it will not
> look nice with another browser at that time you should take care of
> cross-browser compatibility issues of CSS. You should nice and proper
> CSS framework that will prevent to generate cross-browser issues and
> verify HTML tags and CSS properties which may support by browser
> correctly.
>
> **Browser web developer tool** allows outlining an HTML and element with
> different criteria this will allow to writing appropriate CSS for HTML
> element.
>
> **Turn on or off stylesheet with Chrome dev tools**. If you’re wondering
> how your CSS is affecting a particular page element, the Chrome
> DevTools make it easy to toggle each property. In the Google Chrome
> web browser, simply right click and choose Inspect Element from the
> context menu.On the right side of the Elements panel, you should see a
> tab called Styles with some CSS inside of it. This shows you which CSS
> declarations are being applied to the selected element, and if you
> hover over each CSS property, you can uncheck them individually. When
> a property is crossed out, it typically means that it is being
> overridden elsewhere. You may need to uncheck a property in several
> places to actually remove it from an element.
>
> Use **computed tab in chrome dev tools**. it tells you exactly how the
> browser is computing your styles. When working on large projects this
> is essential for resolving cascading issues, problems with selector
> specificity, and more.
>
> You may enable chrome dev tools with **ctrl+shirt+I** or press **F12** key
> which supports in almost every browser.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to debug your css

```
* { outline: solid 0.25rem hsla(210, 100%, 100%, 0.5); }
```

Comment: how to use,could you give more info？